# Silex phpunit not matching routes

Tags: phpunit, silex

I am trying to write some tests for my Silex app and have run into an issue.

I have the following phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit 
     bootstrap="./bootstrap.php"
     backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Management Test Suite">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

The bootstrap code is

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client;

function getJSONResponse($app, Client $client, $url, $params = array())
{
    $params['test_key'] = $app['test_key'];
    $client->request('GET', $url, $params);
    $response = $client->getResponse();
    $data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    return $data;
}
```

My first test file is as follows

```
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['frog_docroot'] . '/www/vendor/autoload.php';

class DefaultTest extends Silex\WebTestCase
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require $_SERVER['frog_docroot'] . '/www/src/app.php';
    }

    public function testInvalidUrlThrowsException()
    {
        $client = $this->createClient();
        $data = getJSONResponse($this->app, $client, '/some/url/that/does/not/exist');
        $this->assertContains('No route found for "GET /some/url/that/does/not/exist"', $data['message']);
    }
}
```

And my second one is

```
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['frog_docroot'] . '/www/vendor/autoload.php';

class AnotherTest extends Silex\WebTestCase
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require $_SERVER['frog_docroot'] . '/www/src/app.php';
    }

    public function testSearchReturnsResults()
    {
        $client = $this->createClient();
        $data = getJSONResponse($this->app, $client, '/packages/search', array(
            'search' => 'something',
            'offset' => 0,
            'limit' => 10,
        ));

        $this->assertSame(array(
            'data' => array(
                '1' => 'Some Package',
            ),
            'offset' => 0,
            'limit' => 10,
        ), $data);
    }
}
```

The issue is that if I run the test individually they both pass.

If I run them as part of the test suite an exception is thrown

```
There was 1 failure:

1) AnotherTest::testSearchReturnsResults
Failed asserting that Array (
    'message' => 'No route found for "GET /packages/search"'
    'code' => 0
) is identical to Array (
    'data' => Array (
        '1' => 'Some Package'
    )
    'offset' => 0
    'limit' => 10
    'more' => false
).
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with how I am trying to write the tests?

Cheers

Comment: Where is the code for route /packages/search

Comment: Have you considered using Behat?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I have been pulled off onto another project. I will reply here if I manage to work it out.

Comment: If anywhere in the project you have `include_once` or `require_once`  remove `_once`! PHPunit doesn't like include_once or require_once!

Comment: @PMoubed I had the same issue and was unable to fix it until I read your comment! It should be the accepted answer IMHO!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. All I had to do (although I didn't like that solution) was to use `require` and `include` instead of `require_once` and `include_once`